# Is there a systematic way in VisualWorks way of generating classes comments?

Tags: visualworks

Is there a systematic way in *VisualWorks* way of generating classes comments. or is it just expected to write them manually when selecting their comment tabs?

It seems like an organized structure for defining abstract data types, instance etc...
Thought maybe there was a comment generator feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comments are meant to contain the intent and purpose of the class, there's no way the computer can understand your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

A class comment can be generated automatically by right clicking the comment text and selecting “Generate Default Comment” from the menu.

The generated comment is rather useless, and you should try to document the class using your own standard.